# Make canvas widens evenly left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas that always expands to 100% of the screen width when manipulating the browser window. I need the canvas center to always be visible in the center of the browser window. The problem is that while I'm expanding the canvas by, for example, 100 px, it expands to the right. Can I somehow anchor this canvas so that it widens evenly left and right?

[incorrectly enlarged canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By456.png)

[correctly enlarged canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC8Cs.png)

Comment: Please include how you're positioning it now

Answer (score 0):

You can change display of canvas to `block` and margin auto it.

Example

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I need the canvas to always have 100% of the width and height of the browser window. I mean that when you reduce the window you can always see the center of the canvas without having to recalculate the canvas coordinates. For this to happen, the enlargement of the canvas must be regular on each side, and at the moment it only enlarges to the right